# specific element in `this` with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

So in jquery, if I want to target a div in the `.test` class on a click I use the following code:

```
$('.test div').click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

But if the "do something" part requires a `this` parameter, I can't seem to get the same effect. So lets say I want to make all bold text in any div with class `test` fade out. I would have to do something like this:

```
$('.test div').click(function(){
    $(this ' b').animate({
        opacity:toggle
    },500);
});
```

**But that is invalid code. So How would I target a specific element in a `this` Jquery selector?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the context as the second parameter to [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

```
 $('b', this).animate({
     opacity:toggle
 },500)
```

Another solution is to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
 $(this).find('b').animate({
     opacity:toggle
 },500)
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code will help you to do this

```
 $(".test").click(function () {
                $("b", this).fadeToggle(500);
 });
```

Take a look at this [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/) site,it has more jquery related faqs. It may be helpful to you.